# Hide layers in preview map in QGIS Print composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I would like to hide some layers in that little preview map on the left bottom corner? See image.  I would like to hide the city and country names as well as the airports-layer...

[image: qgis print composer]

Answer (score 4):

Here are two ways to do this:

1. In print composer, select the map item, check the data defined override button for "set layer list from a map theme" and list the layers by their names you want to show, separated by a `|` as string. E.g. `'layer1|layer3|layer6'`

[image]

2. Check the layers you want to show as visible in your main map canvas. Then go to your print composer, select the map item, and check the box "Lock layers". Once you have done this you can reactivate your other layers again in the main map canvas.

[image]

3. I guess you can also use map themes, but I have never used them before, so I cant really tell how to at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

You can use map themes:

1. in the layertree you can define combinations of visible layers as so called map themes:

[image]

2. in the print composer you can follow these themes for each map:

[image]